# How to swap multiple elements in list (Python)

Tags: python, list, swap

how can we swap the multiple element in the list?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

if i want to swap 1, 2, 3, 4 to the bottom and 11, 12 to the top, like:

```
a = [11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

i've used tuple method:

```
(a[:4], a[10:]) = (a[10:], a[:4])
```

but the output is different, which is:

```
a = [11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

why this is wrong, how can i correct it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to swap the part at the end first or else everything before it shifts.

```
>>> a[10:], a[:4]  = a[:4], a[10:]
>>> a
[11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does this:
First calculates (a[10:], a[:4]) which results in ([11, 12], [1, 2, 3, 4]). Then it attempts to replace a[:4] with [11 12]. The result will be [11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]. Now when the second part (a[10:]) wants to be executed, the length of a is now 10 and a[10:] means adding something to the end, not to overwrite [11, 12].

You should track the length of the two parts you want to swap and index your list accordingly.